# how i can make the iphone browse web as a desktop browser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, user-agent

I just want to ask if their is a way to make the iPhone browse the web as a desktop browser (without telling the server that I am using mobile)? Or if there is a hack I can do to disable detection of my web browser type (mobile , desktop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a browser app on iPhone called **Mercury**
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mercury-web-browser-most-advanced/id331012646?mt=8
you can download it from itunes and from its settings you can choose any browser to simulate as IE&, IE8, Chrome, Firefox. I found it amazing

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to change the user agent in your `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[webView request] valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourwebsite.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:USERAGENT_STRING forHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Just replace USERAGENT_STRING with what ever browsers user agent you want, these are googlable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Puffin Browser](http://www.puffinbrowser.com/), which is a real desktop Chrome browser in the cloud, so it streams prerendered websites to your iPad/iPhone blazing fast and it even supports Flash!

Answer (score 0):

Atomic Web Browser is the best one I found.

Answer (score 0):

Its works for IOS6.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([(NSMutableURLRequest *)request respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:)]) {
        [(NSMutableURLRequest *)request setValue:@" Safari/537.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format your code to make it readable